# How do I properly split a mesh into chunks?

Tags: mesh

I have a large mesh that I want to use as a game map, but because of the amount of large faces, it screws up the lightmaps. To remedy this, I want to split my entire map into equal sized chunks.

I know one method is to create a whole bunch of cubes, or long vertical square prisms in a grid and then simply use the Boolean modifier on Intersect. It works, but it is crude as it leaves artifacts everywhere.

[image]

I had several of the chunks effectively just joined the cubes onto the original mesh instead of *actually* Boolean-ing.

## Is there a cleaner way to split my mesh?

---

For those curious - Here's the original mesh (orange) on top of the results of the above (so artifacts and chunk seams are in black, and some are actual faces).

[image]

Comment: I have some scripts that bisect meshes into grids using bisect. Unlike the boolean modifier they do not fill the cuts.  However, rather than equal area base  chunks, consider  a more logical cut,eg a  block of buildings  that is surrounded by roads, can be split thru the centre of the surrounding road.